# want to know server reboot via manual command or H/W switch

Tags: linux, reboot

I have the linux centos 7 server in datacenter. Server suddently rebooted  but we didn't restart the server and datacenter people also claim that he didn't reboot the server.

Now I want to know how server suddently restared ??

Is anybody run linux command reboot via command prompt or anybody have have directly press the reboot switch in datacenter.

I checked /var/log/message but not able to conculed anything.

Please guid how I can identified via log that its hard booted or via command ???

Answer (score 0):

Check out the output from the last command to make sure it was not rebooted by one of your users/admins it will also give you precise time of the boot.

Here is quick oneliner that will list the last 100 prior the boot event:

```
BOOT_DATE=$(last | grep boot | head -1 | awk '{print $6, $7}') ; last | grep "$BOOT_DATE" | grep -A 100 "boot"
```

Output:

```
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-693.21.1. Wed Mar 21 13:54 - 15:23 (9+00:28)
root     pts/0        <HIDDEN>  Wed Mar 21 13:53 - 13:54  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-693.21.1. Wed Mar 21 13:51 - 13:54  (00:02)
root     pts/0        <HIDDEN>  Wed Mar 21 13:50 - 13:50  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-693.21.1. Wed Mar 21 13:45 - 13:51  (00:05)
root     pts/0        <HIDDEN>  Wed Mar 21 13:43 - 13:44  (00:00)
```

Having the exact time, search in messages for any events before that time.

If you suspect that the system was rebooted by button press, edit /etc/sysconfig/acpid and put the following:

```
OPTIONS="-l"
```

That will make acpid log button presses before shutting down/rebooting the system. Unfortunately it is not enabled by default so you will no see those events for your current incident.

Lastly, if the system lost power/the cable was yanked off, there is no way to know that within the system.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your guidance. 

this is the automatic reboot log that I get from the last -x command . can we get any information from the below log 

runlevel (to lvl 3)   3.10.0-693.11.1. Tue Mar 27 15:49 - 14:31  (22:41)    
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-693.11.1. Tue Mar 27 15:49 - 20:35 (2+04:46)   
    
runlevel (to lvl 3)   3.10.0-693.11.1. Tue Mar 27 15:47 - 15:49  (00:02)    
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-693.11.1. Tue Mar 27 15:46 - 20:35 (2+04:48)